# ZipArchiveEntry charset-encoding error

Tags: java, apache, encoding, character-encoding, zip

I have to create a file zip with `apache-commons-compress-1.x` API. 
I have used the following code:

```
File fileZip = new File("D:\\file.zip");
ZipEncoding zipEncoding = ZipEncodingHelper.getZipEncoding("UTF8");
ZipArchiveOutputStream zipOut = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(fileZip);
zipOut.setEncoding("UTF-8");

File entryFile = new File("D:\\attività.jpg");
String entryName = entryFile.getName();
entryName = new String(entryName.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(entryName);
entry.setSize(entryFile.length());

FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(entryFile);
zipOut.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true); 
 zipOut.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPolicy.ALWAYS);
zipOut.putArchiveEntry(entry);
zipOut.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fInputStream));
zipOut.closeArchiveEntry();

zipOut.flush();
zipOut.close();
```

The zip entry file name has a encoding error. If I open the zipped file with zip manager built windows xp, the filename is `attivit+á.jpg`.
Help me, please.

Comment: You are using the builtin zip manager of XP? Are you sure it's using UTF-8? The output looks more like an 8-bit charset (e.g. CP1252)

Comment: In Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Advance (Tab); there is 65001 (UTF-8) and other code page (Italian)

Comment: Could you use `entryName = "attivit\u00E0-jpg"`? That ensures that the .class uses the right encoding. And the getBytes and such is superfluous. Rests to see what Windows does with that zip.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
entryName = zipEncoding.encode("attivit\u00E0.jpg");
```

Comment: Then the problem is most likely on the Windows side. You still could try "UTF-8" i.o. "UTF8" for zipEncoding. Or do the encoding yourself: `"attivit%U00E0.jpg"` I believe. Better try the zip first with 7Zip or WinZip.

Comment: With WinZip and 7Zip it's ok.

Comment: Then this approach does not work for Windows. Use "Windows-1252" or such i.o. UTF-8, and forget zipEncoding.encode.

Comment: There is still an enconding error, the file name is "attivitÓ.jpg" now.

Comment: I do not know the encoding of your Windows. The zip file will be localized to your area of europe. Windows-1252 is for France/Germany/Italy/...; based on ISO-8859-1. You can look in / use `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`. Sorry very unsatisfying.

Comment: System.getProperty("file.encoding") returns UTF-8

Comment: I never expected UTF-8 on Windows. You could create attitá.jpg under Windows, zip it with Windows, and with java inspect the problem. Detective work should unravel the problem; hexdump of the bytes, char dump (maybe `á` is two chars `a` + `´`).

Comment: The problem is present in Winrar 3.50. In new winrar version this iusse is fixed.